# Has any real-life US military unit committed Die-Hard-2-level treason?

Tags: realism, die-hard-2

In Die Hard 2, a US military unit consisting of at least a dozen soldiers engages in several treasonous acts, from murdering one of their own to freeing an international criminal to helping crash a commercial airliner, killing hundreds of Americans at Christmas. The unit's goal is to make a lot of money, with its members presumably planning to live outside the US for the rest of their lives.

[image]

In real life, has any US military unit or other substantial group of active-duty soldiers ever attempted any treasonous plots of similar gravity to what's depicted in Die Hard 2? Or would the premeditated involvement of so many soldiers in such heinous acts be unprecedented in US military history?

Comment: There have been a number of incidents where very small groups (or one person) commit acts that may be considered treasonous (without being a lawyer) -- but I can't think of anything on the scale you are mentioning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this asks about if any US military unit done such act. Even though movie is not based on any real incident.

Comment: @Panther, not sure why you'd bother, especially with 6 upvotes to date, but suit yourself

Comment: @ShizZ. Because I feel its off-topic. Anyways, if people feel its on topic,anyways it will come out of queque

Comment: @Panther careful. some people are badmouthing users for vtc lately.

Answer (score -2):

Los Zetas might be one of these. They are a Mexican drugs cartel. From Wikipedia: "The origins of Los Zetas date back to the late 1990s when commandos of the Mexican Army deserted their ranks and began working as the enforcement arm of the Gulf Cartel."

Comment: They were not US military...